Using SwapRouter02 in Solidity and it keeps failing
I have been trying to perform a swap on Base L2 in my smart contract using the swapRouter02, it keeps failing. Using universal router works but I really need to use the the swapRouter02.
function _placeSwap2(
    uint256 _amountIn,
    address[2] memory _tokenPath,
    uint8 _routing,
    uint24 _fee,
    uint256 _minAmountOut
) internal returns (uint256) {
    IERC20 tokenIn = IERC20(_tokenPath[0]);
    uint256 swap_amount_out;
    uint256 deadline = block.timestamp + 300;
    
    if (_routing == 0) {
        // V2 logic remains exactly as is
        tokenIn.approve(address(uniswapV2Router), _amountIn);
        address[] memory path = _getPath(_tokenPath);
        
        try uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn,
            _minAmountOut,
            path,
            address(this),
            deadline
        ) returns (uint256[] memory amounts) {
            swap_amount_out = amounts[1];
        } catch Error(string memory reason) {
            revert(string(abi.encodePacked("V2 swap failed: ", reason)));
        }
    } else {
        // V3 swap logic using SwapRouter02
        console.log("Starting V3 swap execution...");
        
        // Approve the router to spend our tokens
        IERC20(_tokenPath[0]).approve(address(swapRouter02), 0); // Clear previous approval
        IERC20(_tokenPath[0]).approve(address(swapRouter02), _amountIn);
        
        try swapRouter02.exactInputSingle(
            ISwapRouter02.ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: _tokenPath[0],
                tokenOut: _tokenPath[1],
                fee: _fee,
                recipient: address(this),
                deadline: block.timestamp + 15 minutes,
                amountIn: _amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: _minAmountOut,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            })
        ) returns (uint256 amountOut) {
            // Clear approval after successful swap
            IERC20(_tokenPath[0]).approve(address(swapRouter02), 0);
            
            console.log("V3 swap successful - Amount out:", amountOut);
            return amountOut;
        } catch Error(string memory reason) {
            // Clear approval on failure
            IERC20(_tokenPath[0]).approve(address(swapRouter02), 0);
            console.log("V3 swap failed with reason:", reason);
            revert(string(abi.encodePacked("V3 swap failed: ", reason)));
        } catch (bytes memory) {
            // Clear approval on failure
            IERC20(_tokenPath[0]).approve(address(swapRouter02), 0);
            revert("V3 swap failed: Unknown error");
        }
    }
    return swap_amount_out;
}

What can I do to make this work?

What error do you get?
